# How to use two arguments for a function being one of them a list of values and the other a number?

Tags: python

I need to write a function with two arguments, a list of values and the percentage that we want to calculate, so for example `function(100,12)` gives me `12%` of 100 which is 12

```
def myfunction(data,percentage):
    return data*0.01*percentage

myfunction(100,12)
```

Until here everything fine, but the question asks me to calculate for a list of values like `[100,25,368]`

```
myfunction([100,25,368],12)
```

gives me an error, how can I use in the argument a list of values as this one and obtain another list with the results `[12,3,44.16]` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using list comprehension:

```
def myfunction(data: List[float], percentage: float) -> List[float]:
    return [datum * 0.01 * percentage for datum in data]
```

Here's how you might do it with a `for` loop:

```
def myfunction(data: List[float], percentage: float) -> List[float]:
    result = []
    for datum in data:
        result.append(datum * 0.01 * percentage)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list calling your function for each value and create a new list:

```
values = [100, 25, 368]

result = [myfunction(value, 12) for value in values]
```

This syntax for creating a list by iterating over some sequence of values is called a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).